# Resize image and send to server in Air app

Tags: apache-flex, image, upload, air, resize

I'm trying to build an Air application where a user can drop in an image. That image needs to resize if it's bigger than 1024px 1024px.

What's the best practice for resizing an image in Air development?
And what's the best practice if I want to send this to codeigniter amf server in Air 2.0, bytearray format?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For resizing the image see [What is the best way to resize a BitmapData object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964495/what-is-the-best-way-to-resize-a-bitmapdata-object) .
And if you want to send it quickly, i suggest to encode the image to PNG/JPG with [ascorelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)