# Simplebutton image is larger than it actually is

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I'm creating a button I use beginBitmapFill method to add image to it. Everything works normally, the problem is that the image loaded by a Loader () is greater than it actually is

Class that creates the button

```html
package mode {
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import org.osmf.net.StreamingURLResource;
 
 public class LoadButton extends Sprite 
 {
  public var Save;
  public function LoadButton(x:uint,save:String,url:String) 
  {
   var button:CustomSimpleButton = new CustomSimpleButton(url);
   button.x = x;
   Save = save;
   addChild(button);
  }
 }
}

import flash.display.*;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.geom.Matrix;

class CustomSimpleButton extends SimpleButton 
{
 private var upColor:uint   = 0xFFCC00;
 private var overColor:uint = 0xCCFF00;
 private var downColor:uint = 0x00CCFF;
 private var sizew:uint      = 100;
 private var sizeh:uint      = 88;
 
 public function CustomSimpleButton(url:String) 
 {
  downState      = new ButtonDisplayState(downColor, sizew,sizeh,url);
  overState      = new ButtonDisplayState(overColor, sizew,sizeh,url);
  upState        = new ButtonDisplayState(upColor, sizew,sizeh,url);
  hitTestState   = new ButtonDisplayState(upColor, sizew * 2,sizeh,url);
  hitTestState.x = -(sizew / 4);
  hitTestState.y = hitTestState.x;
  useHandCursor  = true;
 }
}

class ButtonDisplayState extends Shape 
{
 private var bgColor:uint;
 private var size:uint;
 private var sizeh:uint;
 
 public function ButtonDisplayState(bgColor:uint, sizew:uint,sizeh:uint,url:String) 
 {
  this.bgColor = bgColor;
  this.size    = sizew;
  this.sizeh = sizeh;
  draw(url);
 }
 
 private function draw(url:String):void 
 {
  var myLoader:Loader = new Loader(); 
  var image:Bitmap;
  var uri = new URLRequest(url);
  myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event)
  {
   image = new Bitmap(e.target.content.bitmapData);

   graphics.beginBitmapFill(image.bitmapData);
   graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 88);
   graphics.endFill();
  });
  myLoader.load(uri); 
 }
}
```

How the image is 100x88

[image: How the image is 100x88]

as it is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is showing up cropped like that, is because the BitmapData is larger than the area you are filling.

Before filling the shape with the loaded `BitmapData`, you need to sale it down to the appropriate size.

Based on the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722267/as3-scale-bitmapdata), you could do the following:

```
    var scaleAmount:Number;
    if(e.target.content.width >= e.target.content.height){
        scaleAmount = size / e.target.content.width;
    }else{
        scaleAmount = sizeh / e.target.content.height;
    }
    var scaledBitmapData:BitmapData = scaleBitmapData(e.target.content.bitmapData, scaleAmount);

    graphics.beginBitmapFill(scaledBitmapData);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, sizeh);
    graphics.endFill();

    function scaleBitmapData(bitmapData:BitmapData, scale:Number):BitmapData {
        scale = Math.abs(scale);
        var width:int = (bitmapData.width * scale) || 1;
        var height:int = (bitmapData.height * scale) || 1;
        var transparent:Boolean = bitmapData.transparent;
        var result:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, transparent);
        var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.scale(scale, scale);
        result.draw(bitmapData, matrix);
        return result;
    }
```

It might be easier though, to just make your button state a `Sprite` and add the loaded `Bitmap` object and scale it directly:

```
class ButtonDisplayState extends Sprite
{
    private var bgColor:uint;
    private var image:Bitmap;
    private var size:uint;
    private var sizeh:uint;

    public function ButtonDisplayState(bgColor:uint, sizew:uint,sizeh:uint,url:String) 
    {
        this.bgColor = bgColor;
        this.size    = sizew;
        this.sizeh = sizeh;
        loadImage(url);
    }

    private function loadImage(url:String):void 
    {
        var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        var uri = new URLRequest(url);
        myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event)
        {
            image = new Bitmap(e.target.content.bitmapData);

            //scale the bitmap while retaining aspect ratio
            //scale based off which dimension (width or height) is bigger
            if(image.width >= image.height){
                image.scaleX= size / image.width; //scale it to the width specified
                image.scaleY = image.scaleX; //make the height aspect ratio match the widths
            }else{
                image.scaleY = sizeh /image.height;
                image.scaleX = image.scaleY;
            }
            addChild(image);  //add it to the display list of this object
        });
        myLoader.load(uri); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If I add the addChild it works, the picture is the correct size, but I need to use the beginBitmapFill and then nai works

Comment: what is 'nai"?   I updated the answer to include another example

Comment: Did you find a solution? If you found my answer helpful, please upvote. If it led to your solution, please accept it.  If you found a different solution, answer the question yourself.  If you still need help, update your question or leave a comment.