# Capturing a specific size image from webcam

Tags: flash, webcam, video-capture, image-capture

How can I capture an image from the webcam and have it be a specific size, without whitespace?

I specify the desired size:

`var screenshot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(VD1.width,VD1.height,false);`

That's 400x300

And then I draw to the bitmap from my Video element
`screenshot.draw(VD1);`

I can do `Camera.getCamera.height` and `.width` and see that my camera is 352x264px

When I view the resulting image, I see whitespace all around the edges (colored grey, so you can tell), like this:![enter image description here][1]

If you measure the actual image, you'll see that it doesn't even take up 352x264 pixels. Even with that measurement, there still exists whitespace around the right and bottom edges.

The `Camera.setMode` method upscales the capture to fit 400x300, but it seems like taking a direct capture from the Video object that it's attached to (with `VD1.attachCamera(myCam)` outputs a different result when the VD1 object is drawn to a bitmap.

I'd like all my captured images to be the same size, regardless of camera resolution. Is there a way I Can do this?

---

For reference, here's how I capture the image:

```
private function takeScreenShot():void{
    var screenshot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(VD1.width,VD1.height,false);
    screenshot.draw(VD1);
    var encoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
    var pngByteArray:ByteArray = encoder.encode(screenshot);

    var responder:Responder = new Responder(function(res:Object):void{
        trace("createThumbnail success");
    },
    function(res:Object):void{
        trace("createThumbnail call failed");
    });

    mync.call("saveThumbnail", responder,pngByteArray);

}
```

Here's how I set up my camera

```
VD1 = new Video();
VD1.width = 400;
VD1.height = 300;

myMic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
myMic.rate = 22;
myMic.setSilenceLevel(0);
myMic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
myMic.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0,0);

myCam = Camera.getCamera();
trace(myCam.height+","+ myCam.width);
myCam.setMode(400,300,15);
myCam.setQuality(0,100);
myCam.setLoopback(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably cannot change the dimensions that the image is captured at, but you can resize the image. Here is a link to [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964495/what-is-the-best-way-to-resize-a-bitmapdata-object) with info on resizing.