# snapshot from webcam white border

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Using Flash, I'm talking a picture from the user's webcam and saving it as an image.

The image ends up with white borders on the right and bottom edges, however.

I tried to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964495/what-is-the-best-way-to-resize-a-bitmapdata-object), but that only made the white borders smaller, which is better, but I want them gone.

Here is the code that draws the white borders.

```
VD1 = new Video();
VD1.width = 400;
VD1.height = 300;

myCam = Camera.getCamera();
myCam.setMode(400,300,15); 

VD1.attachCamera(myCam);

var screenshot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(400,300,false);
var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
m.scale(400/(myCam.width),300/(myCam.height));
screenshot.draw(VD1,m);
```

I can do something like:

```
m.scale(400/(myCam.width-40),300/(myCam.height-25));
```

To temporarily remove the white borders, but for certain webcams, like those on a macbook, it doesn't work. How do I get rid of these white borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try capturing the video at some other resolutions:

```
myCam.setMode(320,240,15);
```

I think you want to find the "sweet spot" that will work nicely w/most web cams. The default capture resolution is 160x120. Try resolutions that are multiples of this: 640x480, 480x360, etc.

If you [tell Flash Player to use a capture resolution](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode%28%29) that the web camera does not support (like maybe 400x300), Flash player will find the closest resolution that the camera supports... and I'm guessing this is what's causing the white borders.

Comment: Macbook Pro webcams are supposed to have 620x480 cameras, right? When I `trace` the `myCam.width` and `height`, I get 160x120.

Comment: Web cams support a range of resolutions, so the cam in a MacBook supports resolutions up to 640x480 and various sizes below that. The default capture resolution of Flash's Camera class is 160x120, which is probably why you get those values when tracing the width/height. Don't rely on cam width/height. Set a capture resolution using setMode(), then display it with a Video object of any size (it scales video automatically and you never need cam.width or cam.height).